# Command line switches parsed out of executable's path

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

Why do Windows programs parse command-line switches out of their executable's path?  (The latter being what is commonly known as `argv[0]`.)

For example, [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338728/why-is-xcopy-returning-invalid-number-of-parameters):

```
C:\Temp\foo>c:/windows/system32/xcopy.exe /f /r /i /d /y * ..\bar\
Invalid number of parameters

C:\Temp\foo>c:\windows\system32\xcopy.exe /f /r /i /d /y * ..\bar\
C:\Temp\foo\blah -> C:\Temp\bar\blah
1 File(s) copied
```

What behavior should I follow in my own programs?

Are there many users that expect to type command-line switches without a space (e.g. `program/?` instead of `program /?`), and should I try to support this, or should I just report an error and exit immediately?

What other caveats do I need to be aware of?  (In addition to Anon.'s comment below that "debug/program" runs debug.exe from PATH even if "debug\program.exe" exists.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @zneak: Would "Is there a reason they do this, or was it an accident? If there's a reason, what is it and does it apply to programs I write?" be a better way to word it for you?

Comment: No. However, it would be good if you told the ignorant non-Windows user I am what xcopy should have done, and what it does instead, instead of showing two command lines with very little difference. I don't see how you came to the conclusion that Windows parses command-line switches out of argv[0] just with those two lines.

Comment: @zneak: Desired behavior was not to interpret /w, /s, and /x as command-line switches, which the first does yielding the given error.  It may help you to read the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338728/why-is-xcopy-returning-invalid-number-of-parameters

Comment: You couldn't always use the / as a path separator, so I'd guess that this is just a consequence of the the fact that xcopy predates the use of  / as a path separator, and wasn't worth fixing because the workaround is so trivial.

Comment: @John: Do you know approximately when it changed?  I remember using / for path separator since the Win32 API was introduced (but can't remember Win16), even though some UIs ("Windows Explorer"/explorer.exe being notable) forbid it in some circumstances.

Comment: @Roger: My memory reaching that far back isn't very reliable. But I think NT flavors of Windows have always allowed / but Win3x and Win9x didn't.  I think it was the switch from command.com to cmd.exe where this changed. I vaguely remember that Win32 apps on Win9x could get away with / in paths in some places, but not no the command line.

Comment: Just "" the exe path and the problem goes away, you should be doing this anyway because of the possibility of spaces in the path.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's actually the DOS shell doing this:

My understanding is that DOS chose to use the forward slash (/) for command-line options (i.e., "DIR /s"), *even before DOS supported sub-directories*.  Later, at the point that they introduced sub-directories, they realized they couldn't use forward slashes as the path separator (as was the standard on UNIX), so they had to use the backslash instead.

Also a factor is that DOS doesn't require a space between the command name and the first parameter.  (I.e., "CD\" is the same as "CD \".)

Because of the above, my guess is that it isn't the program that is parsing the command line "incorrectly"-- instead it is the *DOS shell* that is using "C:" as the executable / command name, and the rest as the command line argument(s).  (Of course, a quite test app could verify this, but I'm away from my compiler at the moment.)

Comment: This is correct. If you want an example, try taking `cmd` to a Visual Studio project directory and then running `debug/myapp.exe`. Instead of running your app, you'll end up running `debug`.

Comment: It isn't the DOS shell interpreting it incorrectly (@Anon.: if it was, your program would never execute), it is the program itself---or the C runtime library ("CRT") specifically in this case.  Windows passes the full command-line as a single string, and the program is responsible for breaking it up, this happens before main() begins.

Comment: @Roger: Have you tried my example? You will find that `debug` is executed, and *your program never gets touched*.

Comment: @Anon.: The "debug/myapp.exe" appears to be because of debug.exe existing on PATH.  For example, try `echo @echo %0 > C:\Temp\show.bat && C:/Temp/show` which shows "C:/Temp/show" being passed as the executable.  Compare to `C:/Temp/doesnotexist` which gives "'C:/Temp/doesnotexist' is not a recognized ...".  (In other words, "c:/windows/system32/xcopy.exe .." really is finding xcopy.exe as the executable, and xcopy is giving the "invalid parameter" message.)  You do point out yet another caveat of the Windows shell, however.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that any program doing this would be using `GetCommandLine()` instead of `argv[]` to access the command line arguments, and failing to account for the fungibility of `/` and `\` in user-mode paths on Windows.

Comment: I think this points to the key issue: the Windows API uses GetCommandLine rather than argv-style parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions that might help. These are the result of a class that I made (and use) just to handle parameters and switches.

- I check the argument array to see which delimiter is being used for the path and which is being used for the switches / parameters.
- I personally differentiate between switches and parameters using a slash for one and a hyphen for the other.
- If a switch is passed that doesn't match any of the expected parameters or switches, I check to see if multiple switches were passed with only one slash. This one has caused and will cause more issues for users if they mistype something. For instance, if I were looking for /d /e /l -or- /del SomeThing and the user inputs /del with the intent of passing the d e and l switches.
- In the object, I stuff the switches in a std:: container and the parameter and parameter values in another std:: container which are then made available to the consumer application to process as it sees fit.

Comment: @ISDi: What is the difference between a parameter and a switch, in your eyes?

Comment: Ola Roger, For me, a parameter is data that is being passed to an app. I consider a switch to be a toggle. For example, I would treat "-?" as a switch. It is either there or it is not. I would treat "-pd '/Some/Path/ToProj'" as a parameter.